# Count consecutive characters

Tags: python, string, count

How would I count consecutive characters in Python to see the number of times each unique digit repeats before the next unique digit?

At first, I thought I could do something like:

```
word = '1000'

counter = 0
print range(len(word))

for i in range(len(word) - 1):
    while word[i] == word[i + 1]:
        counter += 1
        print counter * "0"
    else:
        counter = 1
        print counter * "1"
```

So that in this manner I could see the number of times each unique digit repeats. But this, of course, falls out of range when `i` reaches the last value.

In the example above, I would want Python to tell me that 1 repeats 1, and that 0 repeats 3 times. The code above fails, however, because of my `while` statement.

How could I do this with just built-in functions?

Comment: What wrong with using `len(word) - 1`? Would also think you would need to initialize `counter` to 1

Comment: OK that actually helps a lot .... I'll keep working and see if I can come up with a solution!

Comment: why dont you add another if clause checking if i is bigger than len(word)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of specific elements in between other elements in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401733/count-number-of-specific-elements-in-between-other-elements-in-list)

Comment: If your string was, instead, `'100011'` what would you want the output to be? My answer assumes `[("1", 1), ("0", 3), ("1", 2)]` but maybe you want something more nuanced than that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting consecutive characters in a string](/q/13197668/90527)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A solution "that way", with only basic statements:

```
word="100011010" #word = "1"
count=1
length=""
if len(word)>1:
    for i in range(1,len(word)):
       if word[i-1]==word[i]:
          count+=1
       else :
           length += word[i-1]+" repeats "+str(count)+", "
           count=1
    length += ("and "+word[i]+" repeats "+str(count))
else:
    i=0
    length += ("and "+word[i]+" repeats "+str(count))
print (length)
```

Output :

```
'1 repeats 1, 0 repeats 3, 1 repeats 2, 0 repeats 1, 1 repeats 1, and 0 repeats 1'
#'1 repeats 1'
```

Answer (score 81):

### Consecutive counts:

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
s = "111000222334455555"

from itertools import groupby

groups = groupby(s)
result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups]
```

After which, `result` looks like:

```
[("1": 3), ("0", 3), ("2", 3), ("3", 2), ("4", 2), ("5", 5)]
```

And you could format with something like:

```
", ".join("{}x{}".format(label, count) for label, count in result)
# "1x3, 0x3, 2x3, 3x2, 4x2, 5x5"
```

### Total counts:

Someone in the comments is concerned that you want a *total* count of numbers so `"11100111" -> {"1":6, "0":2}`. In that case you want to use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

s = "11100111"
result = Counter(s)
# {"1":6, "0":2}
```

### Your method:

As many have pointed out, your method fails because you're looping through `range(len(s))` but addressing `s[i+1]`. This leads to an off-by-one error when `i` is pointing at the last index of `s`, so `i+1` raises an `IndexError`. One way to fix this would be to loop through `range(len(s)-1)`, but it's more pythonic to generate something to iterate over.

For string that's not absolutely huge, `zip(s, s[1:])` isn't a a performance issue, so you could do:

```
counts = []
count = 1
for a, b in zip(s, s[1:]):
    if a==b:
        count += 1
    else:
        counts.append((a, count))
        count = 1
```

The only problem being that you'll have to special-case the last character if it's unique. That can be fixed with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

```
import itertools

counts = []
count = 1
for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(s, s[1:], fillvalue=None):
    if a==b:
        count += 1
    else:
        counts.append((a, count))
        count = 1
```

If you do have a truly *huge* string and can't stand to hold two of them in memory at a time, you can use the [`itertools` recipe `pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    """iterates pairwise without holding an extra copy of iterable in memory"""
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=None)

counts = []
count = 1
for a, b in pairwise(s):
    ...
```

Comment: @baldr thanks for the `list` cast edit. I forgot it gives you some funky view instead with no `__len__` defined. I prefer to sum the generator in those cases rather than building a list to throw away but YMMV

Comment: Isn't this just counting? What if you separate some of the numbers, like `11122111`?

Comment: @ray Then you get `[("1", 3), ("2", 2), ("1", 3)]`. The OP wants *consecutive* characters.

Comment: If you think they want a count of *all* characters, then you just do `collections.Counter(s)` and call it a day.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I understand what the OP wants. The code you provided groups each consecutive group, and does not provide the total for all the sub-groups you've broken this into, i.e. I was expecting `("1": 6)` instead of 2 tuples with `("1": 3)`. So this seems to be slightly different from what was asked, AFAIK

Comment: @ray I don't believe that's what the OP wants, but have included that canonical solution in case for some reason he means the opposite of what his question says.

Comment: @adam-smith, I also think that the first part is what exactly was needed. This answer is the best as for me. It uses true pythonic-way.

Comment: @ray you'll notice that his sample code only loops while the current letter is the same as the next letter, not while the current letter still exists in the string.

Comment: @AdamSmith: As I told baldr, that's not what I understood when the OP said he/she wanted to "see the number of times *each unique digit repeats*" (my emphasis). To me, that implies getting totals and says nothing about the sub-grouping that you and baldr want to produce. I think the question could've been clearer by posting a sample output.

Comment: @ray well he did post a sample output, but it's not clear which meaning he's going for since his sample input doesn't have any repeating but non-consecutive characters.

Comment: @AdamSmith: I gave you my +1. I think your answer is good and the use of built-in functionality is also better. It was at least my understanding (before OP's edit) that the OP was interested in an algorithm rather than built-in way of doing it.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Yes, but you know I meant the ambiguity here is with the subgroupings, which the OP did not include in the sample, as you mentioned.

Comment: @AdamSmith, why not `len(list(group))` vs  `sum(1 for _ in group)`?  Also, what's the underscore, a wildcard?

Comment: @alancalvitti oof this is a *very* old answer :). `len(list(group))` has to allocate a list, only to access one attribute of it (`__len__`), then throw it away. `sum(1 for _ in group)` doesn't need to do that. This is mostly performance for performance's sake, but if `group`'s length was in the many hundreds of thousands, it's significant. `_` is just a placeholder here. This is a Python convention that means "The syntax requires that I bind this value to a name, but I don't actually USE this value." Also used a lot as `for _ in range(10): action()` (which does calls `action` 10 times).

Comment: @AdamSmith, thanks for explaining. Why doesn't `group` (and similar container objects) support `len` method? Ps in WL, it's `Range[10] // Map[action]`, haven't used for loops since C/C++, it's like going back to assembly.

Comment: @alancalvitti the group object is not a container, it's a generator. Iterating over it to find out when it stops producing values would *consume* those values, and having `len(my_generator)` cause `my_generator` to be empty afterwards is non-obvious. Sounds like WL is more of a functional language -- of course it wouldn't have loops :)

Comment: @AdamSmith, could `group` support a `len` method or attribute similar to `DataFrame` `shape`? I understand generators are lazy/JIT and can be used with streams where length is undefined, but clearly in this situation length is determined.

Comment: @alancalvitti I'm not sure what `groupby` is doing under the hood, but I don't *think* it's doing any work ahead of time, so calculating the length and storing it in an attribute so you can look it up later is doing a lot of work and potentially costing quite a bit of memory to keep from losing those objects when they've run out of the generator. I'm not sure that it's worth avoiding the common `sum(1 for _ in some_generator)` idiom.

Comment: This is a bit old post, but I was trying this `zip_longest` solution and noticed that a reset of counts, `count = 1`, is also necessary as the last `else` statement (just as in the case of `zip`), otherwise the result will not be correct.

Answer (score 3):

#### Totals (without sub-groupings)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

charseq = 'abbcccdddd'
distros = { c:1 for c in charseq  }

for c in range(len(charseq)-1):
    if charseq[c] == charseq[c+1]:
        distros[charseq[c]] += 1

print(distros)
```

I'll provide a brief explanation for the interesting lines.

```
distros = { c:1 for c in charseq  }
```

The line above is a dictionary comprehension, and it basically iterates over the characters in `charseq` and creates a key/value pair for a dictionary where the key is the character and the value is the number of times it has been encountered so far.

Then comes the loop:

```
for c in range(len(charseq)-1):
```

We go from `0` to `length - 1` to avoid going out of bounds with the `c+1` indexing in the loop's body.

```
if charseq[c] == charseq[c+1]:
    distros[charseq[c]] += 1
```

At this point, every match we encounter we know is consecutive, so we simply add 1 to the character key. For example, if we take a snapshot of one iteration, the code could look like this (using direct values instead of variables, for illustrative purposes):

```
# replacing vars for their values
if charseq[1] == charseq[1+1]:
    distros[charseq[1]] += 1

# this is a snapshot of a single comparison here and what happens later
if 'b' == 'b':
    distros['b'] += 1
```

You can see the program output below with the correct counts:

```
➜  /tmp  ./counter.py
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: He don't need just a count. He asks for the consecutive chars. Like: `aabbbcdefabc`: `a:2, b:3, c:1, d:1, ...`

Comment: Replace `for c in sentence` with `for c in zip(sentence, sentence[1:])`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Did something a bit different as that change would not have worked with the previous code.

Comment: @baldr: It produces `{'a': 6, 'd': 4, 'f': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`. It looks ok to me. If it won't work, can you be more specific on what, exactly, you think the issue is?

Comment: @ray, expected output should be `a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, a:4, f:2, a:3`

Comment: @baldr: That's not what I understood when the OP said he/she wanted to "see the number of times *each unique digit repeats*" (my emphasis). To me, that implies getting totals and says nothing about the sub-grouping that you and Adam are producing.

Comment: @baldr's comment describes what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change `len(word)` to `len(word) - 1`. That said, you could also use the fact that `False`'s value is 0 and `True`'s value is 1 with `sum`:

```
sum(word[i] == word[i+1] for i in range(len(word)-1))
```

This produces the sum of `(False, True, True, False)` where `False` is 0 and `True` is 1 - which is what you're after.

If you want this to be safe you need to guard empty words (index -1 access):

```
sum(word[i] == word[i+1] for i in range(max(0, len(word)-1)))
```

And this can be improved with `zip`:

```
sum(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in zip(word[:-1], word[1:]))
```

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is something like this:

Answer (score 1):

If we want to count **consecutive** characters **without looping**, we can make use of `pandas`:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: sample = 'abbcccddddaaaaffaaa'
In [3]: d = pd.Series(list(sample))

In [4]: [(cat[1], grp.shape[0]) for cat, grp in d.groupby([d.ne(d.shift()).cumsum(), d])]
Out[4]: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 4), ('f', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

The key is to find **the first elements** that are different from their previous values and then make proper groupings in `pandas`:

```
In [5]: sample = 'abba'
In [6]: d = pd.Series(list(sample))

In [7]: d.ne(d.shift())
Out[7]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool

In [8]: d.ne(d.shift()).cumsum()
Out[8]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple code for finding maximum number of consecutive 1's in binaray string in python 3:

```
count= 0
maxcount = 0
for i in str(bin(13)):
    if i == '1':
        count +=1
    elif count > maxcount:
        maxcount = count;
        count = 0
    else:
        count = 0
if count > maxcount: maxcount = count        
maxcount
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP wants to count the number of consecutive characters for each character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to count or groupby.  Just note the indices where a change occurs and subtract consecutive indicies.

```
w = "111000222334455555"
iw = [0] + [i+1 for i in range(len(w)-1) if w[i] != w[i+1]] + [len(w)]
dw = [w[i] for i in range(len(w)-1) if w[i] != w[i+1]] + [w[-1]]
cw = [ iw[j] - iw[j-1] for j in range(1, len(iw) ) ]

print(dw)  # digits
['1', '0', '2', '3', '4']
print(cw)  # counts
[3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5]

w = 'XXYXYYYXYXXzzzzzYYY'
iw = [0] + [i+1 for i in range(len(w)-1) if w[i] != w[i+1]] + [len(w)]
dw = [w[i] for i in range(len(w)-1) if w[i] != w[i+1]] + [w[-1]]
cw = [ iw[j] - iw[j-1] for j in range(1, len(iw) ) ]
print(dw)  # characters
print(cw)  # digits

['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'z', 'Y']
[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner that returns the amount of consecutive characters with no imports:

```
def f(x):s=x+" ";t=[x[1] for x in zip(s[0:],s[1:],s[2:]) if (x[1]==x[0])or(x[1]==x[2])];return {h: t.count(h) for h in set(t)}
```

That returns the amount of times any repeated character in a list is in a consecutive run of characters.

alternatively, this accomplishes the same thing, albeit much slower:

```
def A(m):t=[thing for x,thing in enumerate(m) if thing in [(m[x+1] if x+1<len(m) else None),(m[x-1] if x-1>0 else None)]];return {h: t.count(h) for h in set(t)}
```

In terms of performance, I ran them with

```
site = 'https://web.njit.edu/~cm395/theBeeMovieScript/'
s = urllib.request.urlopen(site).read(100_000)
s = str(copy.deepcopy(s))
print(timeit.timeit('A(s)',globals=locals(),number=100))
print(timeit.timeit('f(s)',globals=locals(),number=100))
```

which resulted in:

```
12.528256356999918
5.351301653001428
```

This method can definitely be improved, but without using any external libraries, this was the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

In python

```
your_string = "wwwwweaaaawwbbbbn"
current = ''
count = 0
for index, loop in enumerate(your_string):
    current = loop
    count = count + 1
    if index == len(your_string)-1:
        print(f"{count}{current}", end ='')
        break

    if your_string[index+1] != current:
        print(f"{count}{current}",end ='')
        count = 0
        continue
```

This will output

```
5w1e4a2w4b1n
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#I wrote the code using simple loops and if statement
s='feeekksssh' #len(s) =11
count=1  #f:0, e:3, j:2, s:3 h:1
l=[]
for i in range(1,len(s)): #range(1,10)
    if s[i-1]==s[i]:
        count = count+1
    else:
        l.append(count)
        count=1
    if i == len(s)-1: #To check the last character sequence we need loop reverse order
        reverse_count=1
        for i in range(-1,-(len(s)),-1): #Lopping only for last character
            if s[i] == s[i-1]:
                reverse_count = reverse_count+1
            else:
                l.append(reverse_count)
                break
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I had an interview and was asked the same question. I was struggling with the original solution in mind:

```py
s = 'abbcccda'

old = ''
cnt = 0
res = ''
for c in s:
    cnt += 1
    if old != c:
        res += f'{old}{cnt}'
        old = c
        cnt = 0  # default 0 or 1 neither work
print(res)
#  1a1b2c3d1
```

Sadly this solution always got unexpected edge cases result(is there anyone to fix the code? maybe i need post another question), and finally timeout the interview.

After the interview I calmed down and soon got a stable solution I think(though I like the [groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444401/1518100) best).

```py
s = 'abbcccda'

olds = []
for c in s:
    if olds and c in olds[-1]:
        olds[-1].append(c)
    else:
        olds.append([c])
print(olds)
res = ''.join([f'{lst[0]}{len(lst)}' for lst in olds])
print(res)

#  [['a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c'], ['d'], ['a']]
#  a1b2c3d1a1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution:

```
def count_chars(s):
    size = len(s)
    count = 1
    op = ''
    for i in range(1, size):
        if s[i] == s[i-1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            op += "{}{}".format(count, s[i-1])
            count = 1
    if size:
        op += "{}{}".format(count, s[size-1])

    return op
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_input = 'aabaaaabbaaaaax'
start = 0
end = 0
temp_dict = dict()
while start < len(data_input):
  if data_input[start] == data_input[end]:
     end = end + 1
  if end == len(data_input):
     value = data_input[start:end]
     temp_dict[value] = len(value)
     break
  if data_input[start] != data_input[end]:
     value = data_input[start:end]
     temp_dict[value] = len(value)
     start = end
print(temp_dict)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM: we need to count consecutive characters and return characters with their count.

```
def countWithString(input_string:str)-> str:
    count = 1
    output = ''
 
    for i in range(1,len(input_string)):
        if input_string[i]==input_string[i-1]:
            count +=1
        else:
            output += f"{count}{input_string[i-1]}"
            count = 1
    # Used to add last string count (at last else condition will not run and data will not be inserted to ouput string)
    output += f"{count}{input_string[-1]}"
    return output
```

`countWithString(input)`

`input:'aaabbbaabbcc'`
`output:'3a3b2a2b2c'`

`Time Complexity: O(n)`
`Space Complexity: O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
temp_str = "aaaajjbbbeeeeewwjjj"
def consecutive_charcounter(input_str):
    counter = 0
    temp_list = []
    for i in range(len(input_str)):
        if i==0:
            counter+=1
        elif input_str[i]== input_str[i-1]:
            counter+=1
            if i == len(input_str)-1:
                temp_list.extend([input_str[i - 1], str(counter)])
        else:
            temp_list.extend([input_str[i-1],str(counter)])
            counter = 1
    print("".join(temp_list))
```

consecutive_charcounter(temp_str)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and fastest way to count repeated elements in string

```
    from collections import Counter
    magazine = "aab"
        char_count = Counter(magazine)
        
        print(dict(char_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this as an interview question and got it right with some prompting from the interviewer.  In reviewing my work after the fact, I came across this post.

Here was my basic answer which I think is clearer and easier to understand:

```
string = input()
count = 1
answer = ''
first_char = string[0]
for char in range(1, len(string)):
    if first_char == string[char]:
        count += 1
    else:
        answer += f"{first_char}{count}"
        first_char = string[char]
        count = 1

answer += f"{first_char}{count}"
print(f"{answer}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping `str.count()` would have a `consecutive=False` keyword, but it doesn't. So I came up with this, very likely suboptimal and slow, method, whose major selling point is its use of only one loop:

```py
>>> s='111aaaaaaaabbbdccc5555555555s'
>>> while s:
...  n = s.lstrip(s[0:1])
...  print('%s: %d' % (s[0:1], len(s) - len(n)))
...  s = n
... 
1: 3
a: 8
b: 3
d: 1
c: 3
5: 10
s: 1
```