# How to count types of letters in order?

Tags: python

I'm trying to count letters/input in order.

To summarize, I want a simple system where I can put in "L, L, L, L, R,L ,R ,L ,A ,A" (I know this may be recognizable) but I want it to output something like

> 4 Ls, 1 R, 1 L, 1 R, 1 L, 2 As

My code right now looks like this.

```
def countTheL(word, char='.L,'):
    count = 0
    for c in word:
        if c == char:
            count += 1
    return count
```

(I have identical codes for Rs, As, and Fs) All this does is check for how many there are. It doesn't tell you in order.

I also have another issue if the letter has a full stop connected to it then it is voided and removed, but that can be tackled later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count consecutive characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443946/count-consecutive-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a =  "L,L,L,L,R,L,R,L,A,A"


def count_elements(elements):
    elements = elements.split(',')
    init_char = a[0] # initial character in the string
    char_count = 0  # starting the count 
    count_list = []
    for char in elements:
        if char == init_char:
            char_count += 1
        else:
            count_list.append([char_count, init_char])
            init_char = char
            char_count = 1
    count_list.append([char_count, init_char])
    return count_list


for (i,j) in count_elements(a):
    print(i,j)
```

Output

```
4 L
1 R
1 L
1 R
1 L
2 A
```

but you can of course edit this output

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functionality provided by the `itertools` module (though it's also good to try things out by yourself in the beginning):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['L','L','L','L','R','R.', 'R.','L','R','A.','L','A','A']
output = []

for key, group in groupby(data):
    if not (key[-1] == '.'):
        output.append(str(len(list(group))) + key)

print(data)
print(output)
```

I added the letters ending with a fullstop too, so it's representative.

`groupby` creates groups of your iterable elements and returns them to you as `key, group object` pairs. `key` is your list element so letters with a fullstop will be treated separately (they are seen differently than bare letters). This is used in the `if` statement - if a letter ends with a fullstop, the code skips it. Better said, if it doesn't then it proceeds - and appends a string that is the size of the group and the key - letter.

This is a version that also adds an `s` if there are more than one letter in a group,

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ['L','L','L','L','R','R.', 'R.','L','R','A.','L','A','A']
output = []

for key, group in groupby(data):
    if not (key[-1] == '.'):
        group_len = len(list(group))
        if group_len == 1:
            output.append('1' + key)
        else:
            output.append(str(group_len) + key + 's')

print(data)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a function for every letter, we can just have one function that will go through the string one letter by a time and checking to see if it is the same as the previous letter.

If it is the same letter, we increase a temporary counter by 1.
If not, then we reset the counter and store the counter's value with the letter in a temporary array.

At the end of the function, it will take the temporary array and parse through it to output the number of times each letter is in the string consecutively.

You can use this code that I wrote up:

```py
def countTheLetters(input_string):

    arr = input_string.split(',')

    curr_letter = arr[0]
    count = 1

    counter_arr = []
    if (len(input_string) > 1):
        for i in range(1, len(arr)):
            if curr_letter == arr[i]:
                count += 1
            else:
                counter_arr.append({"Letter": curr_letter, "Count": count})
                count =1

            if i == len(arr) - 1:
                counter_arr.append({"Letter": arr[i], "Count": count})
            curr_letter = arr[i]

        for letter_counted in counter_arr:
            print(str(letter_counted["Count"]) + " " + str(letter_counted["Letter"]))
    else:
        print("1 " + input_string)

countTheLetters("L,L,L,L,R,L,R,L,A,A")
```

This is the output of this block of code:

```
4 L
1 R
1 L
1 R
1 L
2 A
```

EDIT: I changed the code to be able to handle cases of where the string has a length of 1 or 2.

Comment: Thank you for catching that mistake. I edited my code to take into consideration of that test case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
i = 'L,L,L,L,R,L,R,L,A,A'
letters = i.split(',')

count = 0
result = ''
for n in range(len(letters)):
     count += 1
     if n == len(letters) - 1:
         result += f'{count}{letters[n]}'
         if count > 1:
             result += 's'
     elif letters[n] != letters[n+1]:
         result += f'{count}{letters[n]}'
         if count > 1:
             result += 's, '
         else:
             result += ', '
         count = 0

In [46]: result
Out[46]: '4Ls, 1R, 1L, 1R, 1L, 2As'
```

Answer (score 0):

This method returns repetitions of a letter in a string like "A,B,C,C":

```
def count_letters(string, letter):
    letter_amount = len([character for character in string.split(',') if character == letter])

    return letter_amount
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is a one liner (+import), using `itertools.groupby`.

Version without plural:

```
from itertools import groupby
count = lambda l: ', '.join(['%s%s'% (len(list(g)),k)
                             for k,g in groupby(l.split(','))
                             ])
```

```
count("L,L,L,L,R,L,R,L,A,A")
'4L, 1R, 1L, 1R, 1L, 2A'
```

Version with plural:

```
from itertools import groupby
count = lambda l: ', '.join(['%s%s%s'% (len(g),k,'s' if len(g)-1 else '')
                             for k,G in groupby(l.split(','))
                             for g in [list(G)]
                             ])
```

```
>>> count("L,L,L,L,R,L,R,L,A,A")
'4Ls, 1R, 1L, 1R, 1L, 2As'
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a great use of `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools

def count_letters(word):
    return ', '.join(
        f"{len(list(ls))} {l}'s" 
        for l, ls in itertools.groupby(word.replace(',', ''))
    )

print(count_letters('L,L,L,R,R'))
```