# How to find consecutive same items in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I can't solve the following problem.

I have a list and items in it. I need to find 3 or more consecutive items and change them.

For example:

```
mylist = ["BLUE", "BLUE", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "BLACK", "RED", "RED"]
```

Required output:

```
mylist = ["BLUE", "BLUE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "WHITE", "BLACK", "RED", "RED"]
```

There were 4 items found "RED" and changed to "WHITE". Less than 3 "RED" items are unchanged.
There may be an elegant solution, but I still can't find it.

Will anyone help?

Comment: A for loop should be easy to use and help your problem even though it's not the most optimized solution

Comment: This is quite useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443946/count-consecutive-characters

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for the task:

```py
from itertools import groupby

mylist = ["BLUE", "BLUE", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "BLACK", "RED", "RED"]

out = []
for v, g in groupby(mylist):
    g = sum(1 for _ in g)
    out.extend(["WHITE" if g > 2 else v] * g)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['BLUE', 'BLUE', 'WHITE', 'WHITE', 'WHITE', 'WHITE', 'BLACK', 'RED', 'RED']
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally created this code. But there are not as many Pythonics as from Andrej Kesely. Thanks!

```python
mylist = ["BLUE", "BLUE", "RED", "RED", "RED", "RED", "BLACK", "RED", "RED"]
counter = 0
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] == "RED":
        counter += 1
        if counter >= 3:
            for k in reversed(range(counter)):
                mylist[i-k] = "WHITE"
    else:
        counter = 0
                
print(mylist)
```