# Group string by similar substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I'm trying to take a number, convert it into binary, and then produce a list of the length of like terms.

For example, n=49 is represented in binary as `"110001"`.
I would like to return a list of the length of `["11", "000", "1"]`, which is `[2, 3, 1]`.

So far I'm able to convert a number into binary using `"{0:b}".format(n)` but I cannot group the like terms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count consecutive characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443946/count-consecutive-characters)

Comment: `from itertools import groupby; result = [sum(1 for _ in g) for _,g in groupby("{0:b}".format(n))]`

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this task as follows

```
import itertools
t = "110001"
lengths = [len(list(g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(t)]
print(lengths)
```

output

```
[2, 3, 1]
```

`itertools.groupby` does found runs of consecutive same elements (unless 2nd argument is given), `g` here is iterator which is used to create `list` which length is measured. Observe that you can not do `len(g)`.

Comment: It would be more `complete` to include this `n = bin(n)[2:]` before doing the lengths processing. ;-)   As it's more aligned with OP's original ask.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use this after converting your number (careful, it should be in string):

```
from itertools import groupby

bin_number = "110001"
result = ["".join(group) for ele, group in groupby(bin_number)]
print(result)
```

output:

```
["11", "000", "1"]
```

Comment: ah sorry! , add this import : `from itertools import groupby`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def binary_chunks(n: int) -> list:
    return [len("".join(g)) for _, g in groupby(f"{n:b}")]
```

For example:

```
>>> binary_chunks(49) # binary: 110001
>>> [2, 3, 1]

>>> binary_chunks(4) # binary: 100
>>> [1, 2]

>>> binary_chunks(123456789) # binary: 111010110111100110100010101
>>> [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I also ran a [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) test if you're interested:

```
>>> %timeit binary_chunks(49)
>>> 2.28 µs ± 208 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem with the `re` package:

```py
import re
def bit_run_lengths(n, pat=re.compile('1+|0+')):
  return [
           len(m)
           for m in pat.findall(bin(n)[2:])
         ]
```

According to my benchmarking, that's about twice as fast as the `itertools.groupby` solution.

For a more general (single-character) run-length converter, you can use a back-reference. (This is the rare case in which back references are safe to use.) It's slightly slower, but it still beats `groupby` by a bit:

```py
def run_length(s, pat=re.compile(r'((.)\2*)')):
  return [len(m[0]) for m in pat.findall(s)]
```

```
>>> run_length("aabbbbbbbzxxaaa")
[('a', 2), ('b', 7), ('z', 1), ('x', 2), ('a', 3)]
```